# Entity Framework & Code First: Can't get data in one-to-one between ApplicationUser and UserProfile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have custom `ApplicationUser` and create `UserProfile`, but can't get data `UserProfile` from `ApplicationUser`.

Attack Image:

[image]

Please refer to http://www.mediafire.com/file/a9bpajjc44fuewp/DemoMVC6.rar

Update my code:

```
namespace DemoMVC6.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile : EntityBase
    {
        [Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(20)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(20)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public bool? Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class EntityBase
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        [EnumDataType(typeof(RecordStatus))]
        public virtual RecordStatus ActiveStatus { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public virtual DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public enum RecordStatus { Inactive = 0, Active = 1 }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            var trackerEntries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

            //Find all Entities that are Added/Modified that inherit from my EntityBase
            foreach (var entry in trackerEntries)
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    if (entry.Metadata.FindProperty("ActiveStatus") != null)
                        entry.Property("ActiveStatus").CurrentValue = RecordStatus.Active;

                    if (entry.Metadata.FindProperty("CreatedOn") != null)
                        entry.Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = currentTime;

                    if (entry.Metadata.FindProperty("ModifiedOn") != null)
                        entry.Property("ModifiedOn").CurrentValue = currentTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (entry.Metadata.FindProperty("ModifiedOn") != null)
                        entry.Property("ModifiedOn").CurrentValue = currentTime;
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code to the question, instead of whole source code in `.rar` file

Comment: Lazy loading is not yet possible with EF Core ([docs](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html)). You can use Eager loading: `ApplicationUser user = _context.Users.Include(u=>u.UserProfile).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks so much, so I feel Lazy loading is necessary, I dont' understand why EF7 & Core don't support it. I guess Eager loading will improve query during build ^^

Comment: you can take a look at the [discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797) about it.